$R^2$ of regression of residuals when adding an uncorrelated regressor
Suppose we linearly regress $Y$ onto $X_1$, obtaining residuals $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n$. Suppose further that $X_2$ is uncorrelated with $X_1$, and we linearly regress $X_2$ onto $X_1$ (with intercept) with residuals $\epsilon_1',\ldots,\epsilon_n'$. Note these residuals are equal to $\epsilon_i' = X_{i2} - X_2^u$, where $X_{i2}$ is the $i$th observation of $X_2$ and $X_2^u$ is their average. If we then regress the residuals $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n$ onto the residuals $\epsilon_1',\ldots,\epsilon_n'$, one can show that the prediction function one obtains is
$$\epsilon = \hat{\beta}\epsilon',$$
where $\hat{\beta}$ is the same estimated slope one obtains from linearly regressing $Y$ onto $X_2$. This slope is estimated to be
$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum (X_{i2} - X_2^u)(Y_i - Y^u)}{\sum (X_{i2} - X^u_2)^2}= \frac{S_{x_2y}}{S_{x_2x_2}},$$
where $Y^u$ is the average of the $Y_i$'s. Now supposedly the $R^2$ coefficients are also supposed to be the same, but here is where I am confused. Since the residuals have mean $0$, if we regress the residuals onto each other, the $R^2$ should be
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\sum \hat{\beta}^2(\epsilon_i')^2}{\sum \epsilon_i^2} &= \frac{S_{x_2y}^2 S_{x_2x_2}}{S_{x_2x_2}^2 \sum \epsilon_i^2} \\
&= \frac{S_{x^2y}^2}{S_{x_2x_2} \sum \epsilon_i^2}.
\end{alignat*}
But the $R^2$ for regressing $Y$ onto $X_2$ should be
$$\frac{S_{x^2y}^2}{S_{x_2x_2} S_{yy}}.$$
Since $\sum \epsilon_i^2$, the sum of residuals, is equal to $S_{yy}$ minus the regression sum of squares, it seems like the second $R^2$ should be higher. Where did I go wrong?

I'm assuming $X_2$ and $X_1$ are uncorrelated, so that the slope of the regression of $X_2$ onto $X_1$ is $0$. I'm not sure what you mean by the comment about $R^2$. I am not expecting $R^2$ to be equal to $\hat{\beta}^2$, rather I am expecting the two $R^2$ scores from the two regressions to be the same.

Are you talking about "true" slope, or an estimate?

I am referring to the OLS estimator for the slope throughout. Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my post.

OK. Similarly, by $X_1$ and $X_2$ being "uncorrelated", do you mean true correlation or sample correlation?

Sample correlation, so that the estimated slope from regressing $X_2$ onto $X_1$ is $0$.

I see. My confusion was that when I saw $X_2$ regressed over $X_1$, I thought you include $X_1$ only, without an extra intercept. Maybe clarifying that in the post is helpful to others as well.

I think you have answered your own question.
The numerator $\sum \hat{\beta}^2{\epsilon_i'}^2$ is the model SS with no issue, when regressing $Y$ over an intercept and $X_2$.
But the denominator $\sum\epsilon_i^2$ is not the corrected total SS from the same regression. We'd use $\sum (Y_i-Y^u)^2$ as the proper denominator.
The $\sum\epsilon_i^2$ further removed the variability in $Y$ explained by $X_1$. In other words, even though $X_1$ and $X_2$ are orthogonal, $Y$ and $X_1$ are still correlated. Due uncorrelatedness between $X_1$ and $X_2$, the $X_1$ is able to explain some different aspect of the variability in $Y$.
So, the ratio is the "extra proportion of variability explained by $X_2$ beyond what has already been explained by $X_1$".
In other words, the ratio is $$1-\frac{\text{RSS}(Y\mid 1, X_1, X_2)}{\text{RSS}(Y \mid 1, X_1)},$$ but the wanted $R^2$ is
$$1-\frac{\text{RSS}(Y\mid 1, X_2)}{\text{RSS}(Y \mid 1)},$$in which $\text{RSS}$ refers to residual sum square.

I am a bit confused by your answer. Are you saying that the $R^2$ scores from the two regressions (regressing $Y$ onto $X_2$ versus regressing the residuals $\epsilon'$ onto the residuals $\epsilon$) are in fact not the same?

@EthanAlwaise Yes. That's what I meant. Only their numerators are identical, both being the variability of $\hat{\beta}X_2$. But their denominators are different.

Interesting. Thanks. The book "Applied Linear Regression" by Weisberg claims they are equal in the solution to Exercise 3.5.

@EthanAlwaise I guess he might have intended to say that "this is equal to the squared partial correlation of $Y$ and $X_2$ given $X_1$".

@EthanAlwaise In section 3.4.8 of the main text, it is stated that "the value of $R^2$ in the added-variable plot is equal to the square of the partial correlation between the response and the regressor, adjusted for the other regressors in the mean
function."
